# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): when I add Redux connect mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I remove Redux `connect` `mapDispatchToProps` then it's working ok so what have I missed.

When I export like so I get no error

```
export default HandleFiles;
```

When I export like so I get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError):

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HandleFiles);
```

I can't see why???

Here's the error and you see it's in the FilePicker.jsx

[image]

Here's FilePicker.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dropzone from './Dropzone';
import { setNewFiles } from '../../../../../redux/filesData/files.actions';
import {
    enqueueSnackbar as enqueueSnackbarAction,
    closeSnackbar as closeSnackbarAction,
} from '../../../../../redux/snackbar/snack.action';
import * as SNACK_BAR from '../../../../../constants/snackbar';
import HandleFiles from './HandleFiles';

const FilePicker = ({ setNewFileForValidation }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const enqueueSnackbar = (...args) => dispatch(enqueueSnackbarAction(...args));
    const closeSnackbar = (...args) => dispatch(closeSnackbarAction(...args));


    const readAllFiles = async AllFiles => {
        const results = await Promise.all(
            AllFiles.map(async file => {
                const sha = await HandleFiles(file );
                const file2 = new File([file], file.name, { type: file.type });
                file2.sha = sha;
                return file2;
            }),
        );
        console.log('results', results);
        return results;
    };

    function onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
        readAllFiles(acceptedFiles).then(result => {
            // const res = removeUnwantedFiles(result);
            setNewFileForValidation(result);
        });
    }
    return <Dropzone onDrop={onDrop} />;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setNewFileForValidation: newFiles => dispatch(setNewFiles(newFiles)),
});

const enhance = compose(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps));
export default enhance(FilePicker);
```

Here's HandleFiles.jsx

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    enqueueSnackbar as enqueueSnackbarAction,
    SnackbarProgress as SnackbarProgressAction,
} from '../../../../../redux/snackbar/snack.action';

/**
 * Order file chunks with a time-shifting technique:
 * https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing--file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98
 * https://github.com/lvaccaro/hashfilereader
 * @param {File} item
 * @param {function} dispatch
 */
const HandleFiles = item => {
// const HandleFiles = ({ item, setSnackbarAction, setEnqueueSnackbarAction }) => {
    let chunkReorder = 0;
    let chunkTotal = 0;
    let lastOffset = 0;
    const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // bytes
    // const enqueueSnackbar = (...args) => dispatch(enqueueSnackbarAction(...args));
    function HumanFileSize(bytes, si) {
        const thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        let bytez = bytes;

        if (Math.abs(bytez) < thresh) {
            return `${bytez} B`;
        }
        const units = si
            ? ['kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB']
            : ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB'];
        let u = -1;
        do {
            bytez /= thresh;
            u -= 1;
        } while (Math.abs(bytez) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
        return `${bytez.toFixed(1)} ${units[u]}`;
    }

    function callbackRead(obj, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal) {
        CallbackReadWaiting(obj, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
    }

    // time reordering
    function CallbackReadWaiting(reader, theFile, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal) {
        const timeout = 10; // millisec

        if (lastOffset === reader.offset) {
            // console.log('[', reader.size, ']', reader.offset, '->', reader.offset + reader.size, '');
            lastOffset = reader.offset + reader.size;
            callbackProgress(evt.target.result);
            if (reader.offset + reader.size >= theFile.size) {
                lastOffset = 0;
                callbackFinal();
            }
            chunkTotal += 1;
        } else {
            // console.log('[', reader.size, ']', reader.offset, '->', reader.offset + reader.size, 'wait');
            setTimeout(function f() {
                CallbackReadWaiting(reader, theFile, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
            }, timeout);
            chunkReorder += 1;
        }
    }

    function Loading(theFile, callbackProgress, callbackFinal) {
        // var chunkSize  = 1024*1024; // bytes
        let offset = 0;
        const size = chunkSize;
        let partial;
        let index = 0;
        if (theFile.size === 0) {
            callbackFinal();
        }
        while (offset < theFile.size) {
            partial = theFile.slice(offset, offset + size);
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.size = chunkSize;
            reader.offset = offset;
            reader.index = index;
            reader.onload = function f(evt) {
                callbackRead(this, theFile, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(partial);
            offset += chunkSize;
            index += 1;
        }
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // var file = this.files[0];
        const SHA256 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
        let counter = 0;
        const self = this;
        const timeStart = new Date().getTime();
        let timeEnd = 0;
        console.log('timeStart ', new Date(timeStart));
        console.log('humanFileSize ', HumanFileSize(item.size, true));
        Loading(
            item,
            function d(data) {
                const wordBuffer = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(data);
                SHA256.update(wordBuffer);
                counter += data.byteLength;
                console.log(`${((counter / item.size) * 100).toFixed(0)}%`);

            },
            function v(data) {
                const ff = SHA256.finalize().toString();
                console.log('#hash ', ff);
                resolve(ff);
            },

        );
    });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setSnackbarAction: value => dispatch(SnackbarProgressAction(value)),
    setEnqueueSnackbarAction: value => dispatch(enqueueSnackbarAction(value)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HandleFiles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect `HandleFiles` which is not a react component but just a function (does not return jsx). The `connect` function from `react-redux` can only work for react components and thus you get the error.
You can try reading from redux only from `FilePicker` component and pass it on `HandleFiles` function as call parameters